# Create own publishing option on nodes without extra module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I would like to add an option to the tab "Publishing-options" on a node form. I know of the module custom_pub but would like to integrate this in my own custom module to show social media buttons on a node... (Don't want to need 2 modules for this).

This should work for drupal6: https://www.drupal.org/node/538224#comment-2372926 but hook_nodeapi isn't working in d7...

I started with:

```
function hook_social_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    $social_buttons = (isset($node->social_buttons[0]['value'])) ? $node->social_buttons[0]['value'] : 0;

    $form['options']['social_buttons'] = array(
            '#type' => 'checkbox',
            '#title' => t('Show social buttons'),
            '#default_value' => 0,
    );
}
```

But the value of my option isn't saved or updated...
How to continue? -Schould i create a database record for it?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add your own submit function as well. Use this page as a reference for adding your own submit handler:

http://zgadzaj.com/how-to-add-your-own-extra-validate-or-submit-function-using-drupals-hookformalter

Then you would save the value in that submit handler into your own table. You'd probably want to load the value and set #default_value on the form item using the value from the db as well